# How to calculate dynamic created item & quantity JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today i stumbled with some problem with my jquery codes. Basically, i tried to calculate dynamic created item + quantity to get their total price.

Below was my initial code :

```js
   var productPrice = $(".productPrice");
    var productQuantity = $(".productQuantity");
    var totalPrice = 0.00

$.each($('.product'), function(index, val) {
  totalPrice += $(productPrice[index]).val() * $(productQuantity[index]).val()
  $('#total').text(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
  $('#total_price').val(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
})

$(productQuantity[index]).on('change', function() {
totalPrice = $(productPrice[index]).val() * $(productQuantity[index]).val()
$('#total').text(totalPrice.toFixed(2))
})
})
```

Above code are working but they only calculated last item created. I came across SO to find some solutions but not find any (or i missed them).

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found an answer to my own question. What i need to do is match the changed quantity & price array index then loop back all the array price * quantity.

Below was my working code :

```js
productQuantity.each(function() {
  $(this).keyup(function() {
    var index = $(this).data("id")
    calcTotal(index);
  });
});

function calcTotal(id) {
  var subTotal = 0.0

  subTotal = $(productPrice[id]).val() * $(productQuantity[id]).val()
  productQuantity.each(function(index, val) {
    if (index == id) {

    } else {
      subTotal += $(productPrice[index]).val() * $(productQuantity[index]).val()
    }
  })
  $('#total').text(subTotal.toFixed(2))
}
```

This code may help some people had trouble to calculate cart or dynamically created input field.